# How to convert a MIPS string of number to Hexadecimal

Tags: string, binary, mips, hex

I am starting to write a MIPS program where I get a String in hexadecimal representation say A23B , and want to put it together into 1 Entire hex number. I am really lost in the part as how to extract say one Digit , say B and convert it into hex for mips then fetch the other one. I am not looking for an entire program as I know this is not what it is for but as something to start with as I am really lost, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this. Say your data segment looks like this

```
.data
str: .space 5 #enough room for a 4 digit hex number
```

And further, that the memory pointed to by `str` contains the string you want to convert to a number. To get its first byte into `$t1`, you would use:

```
la $t0 str
lb $t1 0($t0)
```

Next, there are four cases:

1. `'0' < $t1 < '9'`
2. `'a' < $t1 < 'f'`
3. `'A' < $t1 < 'F'`
4. Error

I'll assume you know how to check these cases.

In all but the last case, we must increment sum by the given value; therefore the next step for the cases would be:

1. `sum += $t1 - '0'`
2. `sum += $t1 - 'a' + 10`
3. `sum += $t1 - 'A' + 10`

Obviously this is pseudo-code, but it illustrates the main point that the ASCII values for the digits and letters are sequential, so calculating their value is trivial.

Lastly, because we know that each digit represents exactly 4 bits, and because we begin reading from left to right, we must shift the sum left by 4 bits:

```
sll $sum $sum 4
```

That is the steps for one character, to convert an entire string you would need to loop over each character.

Comment: Yeah that helps me get started. Ah, so the string is loaded into separate bytes? That was a problem I had I didn't know how in say storage, word, byte etc a string was loaded. Thank you! I will try to post my full code later to see if I was close if that is okay.   Also, I thought lb would be lb $t1,0($t0) to get the first byte from the string.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on the lb. I'm glad to hear I helped, I would appreciate you "accepting" the answer :)

Comment: Also would you recommend doing methods for the conversion on the cases or just a lot of branching out?

Comment: Nah, these are going to be a couple lines each. You just need a few branches in a row

Comment: All right but for Capital letters , wouldn't I first have to say subtract 65, and then add 10 to convert them to the number the user inputted? Say for D, is interpreted as 0x44 right? If I subtract 65 then add 10, this becomes D in hex representation as the user wanted which is 13 in digit? I will put up my full code by tomorrow if I can't get it fully done.

Comment: Yep, like the code. Interestingly enough, spim actually lets me use character literals as immediates i.e.: `subi $t1 $t1 'A'`

Comment: Ah yeah thank you. Although I am sorry bother you again but while checking and trying to branch I don't know if I am doing this correct. Say for 'a' < $t1 < 'f' , if I use blt $s1, 66, label to check if it is between a and f, how do I check for greater than a as well? bge $s1,61, label ? I just don't know if the branch statements would go one after another thanks.Or I could just ask a new question regarding a lot of branching if that would be better.

Comment: Why would the branch statements not go one after another? Perhaps in a real-world application you might be worried about efficient pipelining, but chances are you're using an emulator and don't have to worry about that.